# Short story where an Asian soldier's DNA is used as a biological weapon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Years ago I read a short story whose plot basically went like this: An Asian man's DNA was used to create a biological weapon.  The weapon was dropped in bombs or pods into an enemy country and dispersed via gas or some other aerosol means, I believe.

The effect on exposed people was to physically mutate and transform them into identical, monstrous versions of the original Asian man, including superhuman strength and chitinous armor growing from the skin.  These transformed victims would then be compelled via DNA programming to kill and consume their own families and countrymen.

The human element was that somehow an aspect of consciousness from the original Asian man was retained in these victims, ostensibly via the DNA, which left the victims (through the Asian man's "consciousness") to collectively lament and regret his participation in the weapons program.

I read this within the past 10 years, and it was either in an anthology or possibly an e-zine like Pseudopod or Escape Pod. However, I definitely read this story. I don't recall listening to it in a podcast.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You say "years ago," but approximately when was this?  Did you read it in an anthology, magazine or online?

Comment: This would have been within the past 10 years, and it was either in an anthology or possibly an e-zine like Pseudopod or Escape Pod.  However, I definitely READ this story.  I don't recall listening to it in a podcast.

Comment: See if it is mentioned here, in literature section: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GeneticEngineeringIsTheNewNuke

Comment: Or here: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/CloningBlues/Literature

Comment: sounds like a very 1960s sort of idea -- that was a time when communist China was considered a mysterious enemy, when no American could visit China under normal circumstances if in fact there was any way at all. I don't think you could even make a phone call there.